# Can't change the output character encoding of servlet

Tags: java, servlets, character-encoding, freemarker

I want to change the character encoding of response object, but after the Freemarker template execution code below executes, the response object changes to committed stage. How can I change the character encoding of response object. Thanks in advance.

```
Writer writer = response.getWriter();
Environment env = template.createProcessingEnvironment(args, writer);
env.setOutputEncoding(charEncoding); // this line doesn't seem to have any effect
env.process();
```

The character encoding is always set to `ISO-8859-1` and I want it to be `UTF-8`.

My environment:

- Google App Engine / Java
- Servlet API 2.5
- Java 7
- Freemarker 2.3.20

Comment: `((ServletResponse) env).setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`

Comment: The `Environment` above is `freemarker.core.Environment`, so it can't be typecast to `ServletResponse`. It's type hierarchy is `Object > Configurable > Environment`

Comment: Not related to the question, but Freemarker 2.3.20 is old, 2.3.23 is significantly better.

Answer (score 3):

FreeMarker writes into the `Writer` that you provide above, so it can't influence the output charset. The key is creating a `Writer` that (internally) generates a byte stream with the desired encoding. For that, *before* you get the `Writer` do:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding(charEncoding);
```

Comment: Good answer, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that you are supposed to mark it as the answer if it works.